# Facebook private images security

Tags: html, image, security

Does Facebook "just" use security through obscurity when showing my images:

```
<img src="some_link">
```

If another user gets the link (maybe just guessing), I'm screwed right?

I'm not worried about my Facebook, just working in something similar and I am not comfortable with just using security through obscurity to protect my users' data.

Comment: Yes, If he can guest it, he can see the image, but in my experience, facebook changes the file name , so it's not practical to to that.

Comment: Ok, thanks @undone. If Facebook does that, I should probably be fine by doing something similar.

Comment: why the downvote? I did a lot of searching before asking this, I think this could help many other people also.

Comment: See this [pic](https://scontent-a-atl.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/t31.0-8/s960x960/10929051_10202496805860416_3488277071740568122_o.jpg), I uploaded this picture as private and no one has access to it but you can download it !

Comment: thanks @undone. Could you post this as an answer? Loving Emma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a URL to a Facebook picture, you can view the picture.
Even stronger, if you get the URL to such a picture, it is possible to deduce the user-id, and thus his facebook account.

For example, the following links to Mark Zuckerberg's profile picture

https://scontent-a-ams.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/t31.0-8/q85/s2048x2048/1932707_10101856181379431_805607187913961174_o.jpg

Take a closer look at the filename:

```
1932707_10101856181379431_805607187913961174_o.jpg
```

The filename is composed out of three numbers. The second of this number is the user-id. We can now visit Mark Zuckerberg's profile as follows:

http://www.facebook.com/10101856181379431

It is even possible to click on the 'previous' and 'next' buttons to see his other pictures.